# Needed: Excel function that accepts Power Automate Desktop "List" as function parameter

Tags: vba, power-automate

I'm trying to get a function working that will accept a Power Automate Desktop "List" as a function parameter. I believe the documentation compares a list to a one-dimensional array but when try and pass a list as a function parameter it fails. Passing the List item by item - i.e., List[0], List[1] works but is obviously not ideal.

Has anyone a solution for this? Would be helping a brother out! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a delimiter (*e.g. ",", "$" etc.*) separated string from `Cloud Flow` and then use `Split()` function to create array from string input inside `Desktop Flow`. There is no other way as of now

**From Cloud Flow :-** `"4141431,4342342,4323243"`
**Inside Desktop Flow :-** `Input1.Split(",")`

Comment: Thank you very much. But if i am sending the List from a desktop flow to an excel macro should the excel function have an input of:

function test ( input_String as String)
     stringer2 = Split(input_String , ",")
End Sub
?